# Using Surface as a CPU, is it possible to use a laptop's display + keyboard to operate it?

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, multiple-monitors, mouse, microsoft-surface

I was wondering if there is anyway that I could have the Surface Pro's screen extend onto my laptop's  - in a dual monitor setup using something like MaxiVista (which does not work with Win8) but one that actually works with Win8) - while still being able to control it using keyboard + mouse from the laptop. Is this possible at all? Hardware options are obviously not possible for the displays (but software over lan?) but the mouse + keyboard part can still be handled using a dock of somekind, no? 
Sorry, if it is confusing but basically:
All the processing is done on the Surface Pro and the Surface acts as one monitor.
The Laptop's keyboard and mouse control the Surface and the laptop monitor acts as the Second Screen.

Basically, is there an alternative (as a single software or as a complicated setup) to MaxiVista that works with Win8?

is this possible??
MaxiVista: http://www.maxivista.com/

Comment: You cannot use either the Surface RT or Surface Pro has an external monitor.  Neither have the required ports to do so.  We also don't provide software recomendations here at Superuser just because the paid solution isn't an option.

Comment: MaxiVista doesn't work for Windows 8. I don't have a problem with paying for it, if it works.

Comment: I've never seen anything except MaxiVista that does this and works at all.  (It's debatable how well MaxiVista works, mind you...)

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely clear on what you are trying to achieve, but as I understand it: you want a software KVM. 
http://synergy-foss.org works with Windows 8.

Comment: No, I was looking for something that would turn both screens, keyboard and mouse into one computer (giving me the ability to switch between both). I basically just need MaxiVista but like something that works with Windows 8 (Maxi Vista does not)